# How to make my hub subscribe to other hubs? (PubSubHubBub)

Tags: python, rss, tornado, atom-feed, websub

Is there a way to make my HUB subscribe to other hubs? Ie. if I find a link with rel=hub, and the hub is someone else's, can I have my own hub subscribe to this topic at this hub, thus making it possible for other subscribers to subscribe to the topic thru my own hub?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [spec](https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) is clear, in a feed, you (the subscriber) are supposed to subscribe to the hub designated by the feed publisher.
So, no, there is no way to get "your" hub to the actual hub for the feed.

Now, some services like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) (which I founded) act as a default hub, and they will of course subscribe to all the hubs for the feeds you use with them.

Comment: Yeah, duh! That's what I want to do. =) Anyway, I'll just figure it out myself. It's simply amazing how questions on PubSubHubBub keeps being closed down as 'too localized'.